# Optimising a set inclusion query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request, query-optimization

My question is about how to optimise the architecture of a database and the requests on it in order to improve performance on set inclusions queries.

I have a PHP/MySQL web-app, including a database with 3 tables :

**Countries**

```
id         name
-----------------------
1          Country 1
2          Country 2
3          Country 3
4          Country 4
```

**Territories**

```
id         name
--------------------------------------------------
1          Territory made of countries 1 and 2
2          Territory made of country 1
3          Territory made of country 3
4          Territory made of countries 1, 3 and 4
5          Territory made of countries 1, 2, 3 and 4
```

**Link_table**

```
terr_id        country_id
---------------------------
1              1
1              2
2              1
3              3
4              1
4              3
4              4
5              1
5              2
5              3
5              4
```

My app often needs to know which territories are included in which.
In the example above we see that territories #2 (country 1) and #3 (country 3) are included in territory #4 (countries 1, 3 and 4), as well as in #5 (countries 1, 2, 3 and 4).

I need a function that lists all the territories that are included in a given territory (for instance, all the territories included in #5 are #5, #4, #3, #2), and one that lists all the territories that include a given territory (for example all the territories that include #1 are #1 and #5). Two different functions, that return kind of symmetrical results.

What is the best way to build such functions ?

So far, my solution is to query via mySQL all the territories and their list of corresponding countries, loop through this list in PHP and keep the territories which country list is included (or contains for the other function) in my territory of reference.

The functions that I wrote are most probably not efficient enough. Moreover, they are called hundreds of times in my system so a gain of a few milliseconds mean a lot in this case.

I have tried to build a single query to get the results, but so far nothing beats my first system.

**EDIT :**
[KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software) [provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796571/2039427) to get the answer in one single request.
After trying it and comparing performance with the function I used so far, it is **twice slower** than my function. This result is surprising for me but I made enough tests to be sure.

I have just tried a third option, which is creating another table that indexes the inclusions between the territories :

**inclusion_index**

```
terr_id_ref        terr_id_child
---------------------------
1              1
1              2
2              2
3              3
4              2
4              3
4              4
5              1
5              2
5              3
5              4
5              5
```

Thus, requesting all the territories included in a territory simply requires the following request :

```
SELECT terr_id_child
FROM inclusion_index
WHERE terr_id_ref = 5
```

Unsurprisingly, this system is literally 100 times faster than my previous attempts. I cannot tell yet how important the toll is to maintain updated this table whenever a territory is added or removed, but I'm pretty sure it is worth it compared to other solutions I tried.

But once again, maybe there is a better solution ?

Comment: You state, **"In the example above we see that territories #2 and #3 are included in territory #4, as well as in #5."**  It doesn't look that way to me.  It looks like territories #2 and #3 are only included in territories #5.

Comment: Please make sure the logic of your question is sound. You seem to ask for two identical function and your own examples don't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the database. I've downloaded it from:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9G-5dTlZuDpdkt4U2QwR1RwRlE/edit?usp=sharing

and recreated your tables. I've now been able to test the SQL commands, which makes creating a correct SQL command a lot easier.

This time I'm sticking with subqueries, but I split them up in much simpler steps, so they're more understandable. I've chosen the territory with id = 1602 as my target. That's 'MAIN EUROPE'.

**STEP 1: Find all countries in selected territory**

```
SELECT country_id 
FROM link_table 
WHERE terr_id = 1602
```

This results in this set:

```
id      name
5       Germany
17      Austria
69      Spain
77      France
83      Gibraltar
110     Italy
135     Malta
183     United Kingdom
192     Saint Helena
```

It's a weird set, but I don't think it can be wrong, given the simplicity of the SQL and table involved.

**STEP 2: Find all countries that are not in the result set of step 1**

```
SELECT id 
FROM countries 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT country_id 
                 FROM link_table 
                 WHERE terr_id = 1602)
```

Again, this is so simple, it must be correct. It is a big set. Now we know that any territory, containing any of these countries, will not be contained within the territory of 'MAIN EUROPE'. To get there we first have to take another intermediate step:

**STEP 3: Find all territories with one of more countries in the result set of step 2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT terr_id 
FROM link_table 
WHERE country_id IN (SELECT id 
                     FROM countries 
                     WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT country_id 
                                      FROM link_table 
                                      WHERE terr_id = 1602))
```

These are all the territories we do not want. So the final step is now easy:

**STEP 4: Find all territories which are not in the result set of step 3**

```
SELECT * 
FROM territories 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT terr_id 
                 FROM link_table 
                 WHERE country_id IN (SELECT id 
                                      FROM countries 
                                      WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT country_id 
                                                       FROM link_table 
                                                       WHERE terr_id = 1602)))
```

Now this almost works, but I found a lot of territories with NO countries at all that are included in the final result. So we need to filter those out:

**STEP 5: Filter out all territories with no countries at all**

```
SELECT * 
FROM territories 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM link_table 
              WHERE terr_id = id) AND
      id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT terr_id 
                 FROM link_table 
                 WHERE country_id IN (SELECT id 
                                      FROM countries 
                                      WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT country_id 
                                                       FROM link_table 
                                                       WHERE terr_id = 1602)))
```

The result set is now:

```
32      France
384     Germany
387     United Kingdom
392     Spain
397     Italy
417     Austria
538     United Kingdom
546     Germany, Austria
627     Spain, France
714     United Kingdom
719     Malta
747     Italy, United Kingdom
1328    Gibraltar, Malta, Saint Helena
1398    France, United Kingdom
1399    Germany, United Kingdom
1402    Germany, France
1602    MAIN EUROPE
1626    Saint Helena
1690    Germany, France, United Kingdom
1720    United Kingdom
1768    Germany, Austria, Italy
1883    France, Gibraltar, Malta, United Kingdom, Saint He...
1885    France, Gibraltar, Malta, Saint Helena
1959    Spain, Italy
1968    France, Italy
```

This is not the nicest SQL command I've ever written, but I think it is reasonably easy to understand. There might be a more efficient variant, but since this executed within 20 milliseconds on my server I don't see the need to change it.

Comment: Thanks Kiko this is very interesting, although it does not work yet. First, I had to change `...C1.id = (SELECT ...` into `...C1.id IN (SELECT ...` as the subquery returns a list of countries. The problem in this result is that I get a list of all the countries that contain AT LEAST ONE of the countries of my `:selectedTerritory`. But nothing prevents those territories from having other ones that are not included in `:selectedTerritory`.

Comment: Do you have an export of you little database? Put a link to it anywhere online. That saves me the time to make it myself, and I can really test the SQL.

Comment: Here you go : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9G-5dTlZuDpdkt4U2QwR1RwRlE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at it. It might be you need two successive SQL commands to get the territories completely included in the given one.

Comment: I completely rewrote the answer.

Comment: This is brilliant ! I just updated it a little bit : I have done the main request on `link_table` instead of `territories`, which allows me to skip the filter for empty territories (that are by definition not in `link_table`). In any case, thanks a lot. If you have any advice for resources to learn how to think like that and build such request, let me know.

Comment: Yes, using `link_table` does make the command quite a bit shorter. No, sorry, no resources, just the advice to practice a lot. The more you do it, the better you get at it. I use StackOverflow for this, and your question what a nice challenge.

Comment: After further testing, I have updated my question, and unfortunately had to uncheck your answer from the best because of the results...

Comment: Yes, speed isn't great with all those subquery's. If speed is your ultimate goal you could just compute all results once, store them, and then simply look them up. There's nothing faster than that. Afterall, the territories won't change that often. Or will they?

Comment: Yeah, in my case they will change as a lot are created on the go (except if I store once and for all all the possible combinations, which is completely suboptimal I would say) and other are changed by the user. So far, an index table seems the best.